# Analytic function and power series.

Tags: real-analysis

**Q1)** Is there a correlation between that for exemple $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ on all $\mathbb R$ and the fact that $x\mapsto e^x$ is analytic on $0$ ? In general, if $f$ is analytic on $0$ and that $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ in a neighborhood of $0$, if $\mathcal R$ is the radius of convergence of the series, do we have that $$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nx^n$$ on all $]-\mathcal R,\mathcal R[$ ?

**Q2)** I have seen that on $\mathbb R$ if $f$ is analytic on $x=a$ the it's infinitely derivable in $x=a$ but the reciprocal is wrong. Could you give me an example of a function which is infinitely derivable but not analytic ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Comment: The answer to Q1 is "yes".

Comment: @uniquesolution: Thanks. Could you give me a web site where I can find a proof ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to Q2), consider the function 
\begin{align*}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 &\mbox{ if } x \leq 0, \\
e^{-\frac{1}{x}} &\mbox{ if } x > 0.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This function is infinitely differentiable at 0 (since the function $x \mapsto e^{-x}$ decays faster than any power of $x$ at $\infty$) and, in fact, all derivatives satisfy $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$.  Hence, $f$ is not analytic at $x = 0$ since $f(x)$ is not identically 0 in a neighborhood of $x = 0$.